# keras_vggface: No module named 'keras.engine.topology'

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, keras-vggface

There are several tutorials online that import a VGGFace model from keras_vggface like this:

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.topology'
```

This problem happens on my local machine, but also on Google Colab after installing `keras_vggface` with

```
!pip install keras_vggface
```

Answer (score 8):

I solved this issue in Google Colab by changing the import from

```
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
```

to

```
from keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs
```

in `usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_vggface/models.py`

Comment: works, thanks!! (also for m1 Macs)

Comment: where is that models on windows? I can not find it

Answer (score 6):

```
! pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface.git
!pip install keras_applications --no-deps
filename = "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_vggface/models.py"
text = open(filename).read()
open(filename, "w+").write(text.replace('keras.engine.topology', 'tensorflow.keras.utils'))
import tensorflow as tf

from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace

vggface = VGGFace(model='resnet50') # or VGGFace() as default
```

worked for me and colab

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install it as below:

```
!pip install keras_vggface
```

It should work

Comment: Thanks @Prophet. Unfortunately the problem is there after I installed it.