# Get 'No module named 'keras.engine.topology'' when I try to import keras_vggface

Tags: python, keras, modulenotfounderror, keras-vggface

When I try to import vggface (after successful install) I get the message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.topology'
```

Does anyone know why this is the case and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keras\_vggface: No module named 'keras.engine.topology'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862735/keras-vggface-no-module-named-keras-engine-topology)