# Getting import error in tensorflow.keras.prepocessing in VSCODE python fi

Tags: python, bash, powershell, visual-studio-code, keras

when I am writing the code in PowerShell in vscode

```
 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
 from keras_vggface.utils import preprocess_input
 from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
```

**I am getting this error. Help me with this**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/02_feature_extractor.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras_vggface.utils import preprocess_input
  File "C:\Users\shana\Desktop\face_match\env\lib\site-packages\keras_vggface\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>    from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
  File "C:\Users\shana\Desktop\face_match\env\lib\site-packages\keras_vggface\vggface.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras_vggface.models import RESNET50, VGG16, SENET50  File "C:\Users\shana\Desktop\face_match\env\lib\site-packages\keras_vggface\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.topology'
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862735/keras-vggface-no-module-named-keras-engine-topology, maybe it helps!

Comment: I checked that, but it didn't work in VSCODE

Comment: Can you provide your whole script?

Comment: The title is misleading, the error has nothing to do with keras preprocessing

Comment: Which versions of tensorflow, keras and janggu are you using? The issue is likely related to using incompatible library versions. Please use: tensorflow==2.2, keras==2.4.3 and janggu==0.10.2 (or follow the alternative installation instructions on the readme page). Thank you very much

Comment: @Shanu Does my solution solve your issue?